# Parameter![paramname].label (0) = #error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-expression

im using a visual studio expression

```
=parameter!site.label(0)
```

the user can select all/ multiple values for this parameter 
but the parameter is only showing the first one

say user selected all (birm,londn,leeds) 
the field should say birm, londn,leeds but it only says birm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display multi parameter selections then do this

`=Join(Parameters!xxxxxxx.Value,",")`

Comment: Thanks Bro ! i needed Join(Parameters!xxxxxxx.Label,",")